# authorization failed when login with twitter in my android app using twitter kit sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, twitterkit

I am using the twitter kit to permit to users logging with twitter through my Android app. Everything looks right and i configured my app in the twitter developer console but when I try to login with Twitter the first time I get this error

E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:171)
        at tn.app.boostiny.views.auth.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:200)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7741)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4750)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4799)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.Activit
yThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)

PS : The twitter app is installed and the second time I can login without any error.
I added twittersdk:// on the callback url too.

---

UPDATED :

I want to add some details.
When I login the first time a black sreen appear for a few seconds before opening the twitter authorization interface.

Comment: Twitter Kit is no longer developed or supported by Twitter. It's not clear from this error what the problem might be, but you'd have to see if anyone has forked and fixed the archived open source code if it is something internal to the library. Was the Twitter app running in the background the first time around?

Comment: @andy piper yes